# MongoDB and IP subnets

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Let's say we have a collection of documents like that:

```
{'ip':'10.1.1.1','someattr':'aaa'}
{'ip':'120.14.15.16','someattr':'bbb'}
{'ip':'212.12.12.12','someattr':'ccc'}
```

I would like to find all documents where **ip** is in some IP subnet.
I use python and can convert subnet to array and run something like

```
coll.find( { 'ip': { '$in': [ '10.1.1.0', '10.1.1.1', '10.1.1.2' ] } } )
```

But it looks normal only for small subsets, for example netmask /20 will have 4094.

Comment: you could do a prefixed regex on the supernet segment finding all subnet addresses

Comment: Why are you storing them like this? Did you consider storing parts separately? Or storing one integer?

Comment: @Sammaye: yeah, seems that regex can work here.

Comment: Sergio, for some reasons I can't change DB scheme.

Comment: Regexp sounds interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a binary key for that and query using $gt/$lt ranges. Should be much more efficient than the regex version.

Pseudo code:

```
db.mycol.find({_id: {$gte: BinData([255,255,0,0]), $lte: BinData([255,255,255,255])}})
```

Comment: Indeed though using ints would be even more performant which is what's normally used

Answer (score 1):

Would regex help you? mongodb supports regex:

python code:

```
regx = re.compile('10.*', re.IGNORECASE)
coll.find( { 'ip': regex } )
```

should find all ips beginning with '10' - you should be able to transition this to your required subnet mask for the ip address.